# TimThumb cache folder cannot be deleted or edited

Tags: php, caching

I'm not sure what the issue is, because I can delete and modify files in the same directory level with no problem. Here is the script I'm running to sort through all my directories and locate any TimThumb caches.

```
$caches = array();
function searchForThumbCaches($dir=false, &$results=false) {
    if ( !is_array($results) )
        $results = array();
    if ( !$dir )
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    $thumbFileFound = false;
    $cacheDirFound = false;
    //echo 'Scanning dir `'.$dir.'`';
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $item) {
        $path = slash($dir.'/'.$item);
        if ( $item == '.' || $item == '..' )
            continue;

        //echo 'Found item `'.$item.'` (`'.$path.'`)<br />';
        if ( $item == 'cache' && is_dir($path) )
            $cacheDirFound = true;

        if ( $item == 'thumb.php' )
            $thumbFileFound = true;

        if ( is_dir($path) )
            searchForThumbCaches($path, $results);
    }

    if ( $thumbFileFound && $cacheDirFound )
        $results[] = slash($dir.'/cache');


    return $results;

}

$thumbCaches = searchForThumbCaches();

foreach($thumbCaches as $cachePath) {
    chmod($cachePath, 0777);
    echo 'Cache `'.$cachePath.'`<br />';
    foreach(scandir($cachePath) as $cacheFile) {
        if ( $cacheFile == '.' || $cacheFile == '..' || $cacheFile == 'index.html' )
            continue;
        $path = slash($cachePath.'/'.$cacheFile);
        unlink($path);
    }
}
```

However, neither the `chmod()` or `unlink()` operations work, they both return errors, like this sample output:

```
Cache `/var/www/example.com/web/engine/img/dashboard/cache`

Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/example.com/web/thumb.cache.clear.php on line 46

Cache `/var/www/example.com/web/engine/ui/themes/default/img/dashboard/cache`

Warning: unlink(/var/www/example.com/web/engine/ui/themes/default/img/dashboard/cache/timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch): Permission denied in /var/www/example.com/web/thumb.cache.clear.php on line 52
```

I've tried deleting them in an FTP client like CyberDuck, but nothing I do seems to work. Is there anyway to override these permissions or am I just out of luck?